# php/Wordpress/Ajax Button call a php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm just beginning to learn PHP and I am developing a WordPress plugin. But I have a problem. When I press a button, I want it to call a PHP script where I have a different SQL request to execute and others things without changing page. I know I need to use Ajax but I don't understand how use it and where I write it. Could you help me please?

**index.php** is where I have a function that prints a list with checkbox and the **button** to execute the script **createInsert.php**

PS: Sorry for my bad English.

**index.php**

```
 <?php
   public function pref_liste_checkbox(){
        global $wpdb; 

        print '<h3>Composition de la liste synthetique</h3>';
        print '<form method="POST" action=" "><table border="1"><tr><th>Attributs</th><th>Choix</th></tr>';

        $resultat= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from wp_frm_fields ",ARRAY_N); 

        foreach ($resultat as $post) {      
           print'<tr>';
           echo '<td>'.$post[2].'</td>';
           echo"<td><center><input type='checkbox' name='choixP[]'value='".$post[0]."'></center></td>";
        }

        print '</tr><input type="submit" name ="execute"value="execute"></table></form>';
    }
?>
```

**createInsert.php**

```
<?php
     //if the table exist =1 
    if(FrmStatisticsController::table_ok('testWP','wp_users')==1){

    ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                    var r = confirm("Voulez-vous vraiment mettre à jour les attributs de la liste synthétique?");
                    if (r == true) {

                        <?php
                                ///////////CLEAN LA TABLE//////////
                                ////////////INSERT INTO/////////

                        ?>
                        var f = alert("MàJ réussie !");

                    }else {
                                ///////////Aucune Action\No Action////////
                    }

            </script>
    <?php

    } else (FrmStatisticsController::table_ok('testWP','wp_users')==0){

    ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                    var r = confirm("Voulez-vous sauvegarder les attributs de la liste synthétique?");
                    if (r == true) {

                        <?php
                                ///////////CREATE TABLE//////////

                                global $wpdb;
                                $nom_table = $wpdb->prefix .'choix_attributs_liste';
                                $sql = "CREATE TABLE $nom_table ( mytable_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, att_name varchar(255), att_id bigint(20),PRIMARY KEY(mytable_id));";
                                dbDelta($sql);

                                ////////////INSERT INTO/////////
                        ?>

                        var f = alert("Création et insertion des n-uplets réussie!");

                    }else {
                                ///////////Aucune Action\No Action////////
                    }

            </script>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a simple ajax tutorial and when you know how to use it, then you can try to incorporate it into a wp plugin.

Comment: I think you should see some plugin creating tutorial

Comment: first of all for plugin you dont put your code in index,php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your Question is for the button but there is these point you should look at before .

1. to create plugin there is standards ... see this tool will help you get the files ... and set the basic plugin ready `http://wppb.me/`
2. check some tutorials

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

3. search for other plugins before create one ( so you don't reinvent the wheel )
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: Yes, I know I use a MVC architecture I just use 2 randoms names for this example. But thank you for your answer and your links I'll check them.

Comment: its not liek you dont know wordpress plugins have it own structure and best practices ... if this answer solve your problem you can mark it as accepted